# Nodejs Crypto ECDH PublicKey Hex as X.509

Tags: java, node.js, cryptography, ecdsa

I am using the `prime256v1` curves for generating key pairs and sign using `nodejs` with the default `crypto` module.

### Using `crypto`

```
let crypto = require('crypto');
let e = crypto.createECDH('prime256v1');
e.generateKeys();
privateKey = e.getPrivateKey();
privateKeyHex = privateKey.toString('hex');
publicKey = e.getPublicKey();
publicKeyHex = publicKey.toString('hex');
```

I obtain a publickey which looks like the hex string below:

```
'049a6b0ac242afe41128cf59736412686ca83c9e902ee3fa0f13810b9d59ebfe5e49204427c23b630be12ae33815b0bda6ed8d0603386c6ea5f1906cdb0e731286'
```

### Usign `jsrsasign`

```
let jsrsa = require('jsrsasign');
let KEYUTIL = jsrsa.KEYUTIL;
let kp = KEYUTIL.generateKeypair("EC", "prime256v1");
let pkHex = kp.pubKeyObj.pubKeyHex
```

which returns

```
'04f36e41189420db05dd8a73e3cb310b0c55809190bdedd89bf19769ac8df3cd06c1380f646e9e65e31c24affff79e43516b37e0186c3753cfdfd29894c2becc84'
```

### Converting the PublicKey Hex to PublicKey object in Java

I want to use these publicKeys and convert it into a `PublicKey` object in `java`. Using the `EC` KeyFactory, I convert the hex to a `byte[]` and try to construct the `PublicKey` object in java which expects a X.509 format encoding.

```
public PublicKey getPublicKey(byte[] pk) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(pk);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
    PublicKey pub = kf.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
    return pub;
}
```

To convert the hex string to a `byte[]` I use the following:

```
public byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String hexString) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[hexString.length() / 2];

    for(int i = 0; i < hexString.length(); i += 2) {
        String sub = hexString.substring(i, i + 2);
        Integer intVal = Integer.parseInt(sub, 16);
        bytes[i / 2] = intVal.byteValue();
        String hex = "".format("0x%x", bytes[i / 2]);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Trying to do the same using the test case as follows results in an `InvalidKeySpecException`:

```
@Test
public void pkConversionTest() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    ECDSA.setDebug(true);
    byte[] pk = hexStringToByteArray("049a6b0ac242afe41128cf59736412686ca83c9e902ee3fa0f13810b9d59ebfe5e49204427c23b630be12ae33815b0bda6ed8d0603386c6ea5f1906cdb0e731286");
    PublicKey pub = ECDSA.getPublicKey(pk);
    System.out.println(pub);
}
```

returns

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=26, too big.
```

I am however able to generate a `KeyPair` using `java` and use the publicKey hex obtained with `nodejs` to perform signature `verify`. A sample publickey hex generated from java looks as follows:

```
3059301306072a8648ce3d020106082a8648ce3d0301070342000425a321d5a1a74e6c04a6e3cab030401f3dbc04d5242f9bc629175c3d3988799175eb80cd96d7e76ea924630a8d86b93c54dec7cb965b58de31705eb3343846a1
```

How do I format the publicKey generated by nodejs in an X.509 format to be used on the java's side?

#### Edit:

`3059301306072a8648ce3d020106082a8648ce3d030107034200` seems to be a common prefix for the publicKey hexes generated using `java`. By `Prefix`ing this to the hex values of the PublicKey obtained using `nodejs` since the length is smaller seems to solve the problem. But can someone explain why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But can someone explain why?

**Java encodes public keys in "X.509" format** or more exactly the `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` structure (SPKI) defined by X.509/PKIX; see rfc5280, rfc3279, and for ECC specifically rfc5480. That's why the data you pass to the key factory is in a class named `X509EncodedKeySpec`. This ASN.1 structure contains an `AlgorithmIdentifier` which identifies the algorithm used and its parameters (which for ECC is the curve/group used, in your case an OID identifying prime256 aka P-256 aka secp256r1) plus a BIT STRING type containing the actual encoded publickey value (which for ECC is the point in X9.62 format, which has several variants; here you are using uncompressed; according to [the doc](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_ecdh_getpublickey_encoding_format) nodejs.crypto also supports compressed).

Your "prefix" is the DER encoding of the ASN.1 outer SEQUENCE, AlgorithmIdentifier, and tag length and padcount which begin the BIT STRING to contain the publickey point.

Basically dupe:
* [How can I get a PublicKey object from EC public key bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26159149/how-can-i-get-a-publickey-object-from-ec-public-key-bytes?rq=1)
* [Loading raw 64-byte long ECDSA public key in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445997/loading-raw-64-byte-long-ecdsa-public-key-in-java) (Maarten's answer is effectively what you did)
* [How can I generate a valid ECDSA EC key pair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40155888/how-can-i-generate-a-valid-ecdsa-ec-key-pair) (disclosure: mine)

FYI: Effectively the same issue also occurs for RSA and there are more Qs on that.
And there are also similar issues with privatekeys in generic PKCS8 format compared to algorithm-specific formats, but since publickeys are usually exchanged with other systems and/or programs while privatekeys usually aren't interoperability of privatekey encoding is less often a concern.