# Using a base64 encoded public key in Java

Tags: java, openssl, cryptography, ecdsa, sasl

There is an application that creates a base64 encoded public key with the following commands:

```
openssl ecparam -genkey -name prime256v1 -out ecdsa.pem
openssl ec -noout -text -conv_form compressed -in ecdsa.pem | grep '^pub:' -A 3 | tail -n 3 | tr -d ' \n:' | xxd -r -p | base64
```

How do I use this public key in Java? According to my research it should work with this code, but I get an exception that the key is too long:

```
EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode("base64-from-above");
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
```

Comment: The Java code expects a key in X.509/SPKI format. The key generated with OpenSSL is a compressed public key. Both are different formats, so a conversion is necessary. Can you use BouncyCastle? Regarding an example, what do you need the key for, ECDH or ECDSA? Can you post an example key just to be sure?

Comment: Just execute the commands above. Example: A0rMwyEJQnTGfW9Wcx60sNS3X1xS9Th5Wsz3519Kacw7

Comment: I need it for ECDSA and BouncyCastle is possible I think. Thanks so far!

Comment: Mostly dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52232996/nodejs-crypto-ecdh-publickey-hex-as-x-509 and more linked there