# Android Keystore EDCSA (secp256r1) Public Key always invalid

Tags: android, android-keystore

I am currently trying to create an EDCSA Key Pair with the Android Keystore.
Creation works fine but when sending the key to the backend I receive "Invalid EDCSA Key".
I have no insight into the backend implementation.

The website: https://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/sample/sample-ecdsa.html

Also marks the created key(s) as having an invalid signature.

My code is as follows:

```
val keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_EC, "AndroidKeyStore")
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(
        KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                "key4",
        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN)
        .setAlgorithmParameterSpec(ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1"))
        .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
        .setUserAuthenticationRequired(false)
        .build())
    val keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair()
    val p = KeyFactory.getInstance(keyPair.public.getAlgorithm()).generatePublic(
        X509EncodedKeySpec(keyPair.public.getEncoded()))
    hexPublic = Hex.toHexString(p.encoded)
```

Resulting in for example:

```
Public-Key: (256 bit)
00000000  04 6e 33 8a 49 1a 96 de  e8 b6 53 a7 b6 4a df 33  |.n3.I.....S..J.3|
00000010  b5 23 ce 92 2d 39 2e a2  f0 cc 19 ec 54 cf ad d7  |.#..-9......T...|
00000020  6e e1 ce 78 c7 61 c4 01  f4 7b 64 2a a4 32 03 4b  |n..x.a...{d*.2.K|
00000030  8d 29 e4 8f 16 6e d6 82  ce bf 07 b9 30 97 15 ff  |.)...n......0...|
00000040  d1                                                |.|
```

Encoded from above results in:

```
3059301306072a8648ce3d020106082a8648ce3d030107034200046e338a491a96dee8b653a7b64adf33b523ce922d392ea2f0cc19ec54cfadd76ee1ce78c761c401f47b642aa432034b8d29e48f166ed682cebf07b9309715ffd1
```

After initial searching I found the addition:

```
KeyFactory.getInstance(keyPair.public.getAlgorithm()).generatePublic(X509EncodedKeySpec(keyPair.public.getEncoded()))
```

To remove unnecessary padding from my key.

But still the key looks way different than what the website creates as an example:

```
04d8888078160aa934ace1745efb1d00ddec4a0e73ea93931902784c57c6ac604df3898241c1925e42907419d6d0ce5956d4109964608749aedc69e1e532c018c9
```

The content of the public key above(not encoded) seems to have the right format, but when trying it on the website it still is marked as invalid signature.

I am not sure what to do to get the correct value from the key, I am happy for any pointers and or help.

p.S. tried: [How can I generate a valid ECDSA EC key pair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40155888/how-can-i-generate-a-valid-ecdsa-ec-key-pair)

which also is not working.

**Update**
Found out that we need an ASIN 9.63 key format to make it work with the backend

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hey @Koerfer_P, I'm having the same issue. Would you mind elaborating on your solution with the "ASIN 9.63 key format", please? Thanks!