# ECDSA KeyPairGenerator not available (but in JUnit works)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, bouncycastle

I am getting below Exception which I observed when running Android app - it does not occurs when I run the code below as JUnit.

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: ECDSA KeyPairGenerator not available
    at java.security.KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyPairGenerator.java:225)
    at com.mhamdaoui.smartcardreader.CryptoUtils$Companion.getMerchantEphemeralPublicKey(CryptoUtils.kt:48)
    at com.mhamdaoui.smartcardreader.MainActivity.onTagDiscovered(MainActivity.kt:80)
    at android.nfc.NfcActivityManager.onTagDiscovered(NfcActivityManager.java:603)
    at android.nfc.IAppCallback$Stub.onTransact(IAppCallback.java:83)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:573)
```

The code:

```
  Security.addProvider(BouncyCastleProvider())
  val generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA")
  val ecSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp256r1")
  generator.initialize(ecSpec)
  val keyPair = generator.generateKeyPair()
  val publicKey = keyPair.public as ECPublicKey
  return publicKey.q.getEncoded(true)
```

How to resolve this issue?

**UPDATE**

When I am creating JUnit in test (I am using Android Studio):

```
@Test
fun compressedGeneratorTest() {
  Security.addProvider(BouncyCastleProvider())
  val generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA")
  val ecSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp256r1")
  generator.initialize(ecSpec)
  val keyPair = generator.generateKeyPair()
  val publicKey = keyPair.public as ECPublicKey
  val encoded = publicKey.q.getEncoded(true)
  assert(true)
}
```

Everything works also. How to resolve this issue on App runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that it is not possible to use BounceyCastle on Android - instead use SpongyCastle:

```
implementation 'com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.54.0.0'
implementation 'com.madgag.spongycastle:pkix:1.54.0.0'
```

And then initialize the provider with BouncyCastleProvider instance like below:

```
Security.addProvider(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider())
```

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of BouncyCastle libraries can be used to generate keypairs using `ECDSA` algorithm on Android device with the below mentioned steps.

Include the latest bouncy castle library by adding the below dependencies.

```
    implementation "org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15to18:1.68"
    implementation "org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15to18:1.68"
```

> Note: Refer [Provider](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15to18), [PKIX](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15to18) to get the latest version details.

After adding the libraries, follow any of the below mentioned approach based on the mentioned need.

#### Approach 1

If you want to use the provider entire application level, replace the Android OS Bouncycastle provider with the provider from the added library using below line.

```
// Remove the OS provided bouncy castle provider
Security.removeProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME)
// Add the bouncy castle provider from the added library
Security.addProvider(org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider())
```

#### Approach 2

If you don't want to replace the Provider throughout the application, you can pass the provider instance to the `KeyPairGenerator` like below.

> Java

```
KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA", new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider())
```

> Kotlin

```
val generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA", org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```kotlin
implementation("org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.70")
```